# Why does the first column appear as the word 'data' when inserting columns into PostgreSQL using psycopg2?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

When adding columns to PostgreSQL using Python's psycopg2 module, why does the first column name always appear as the word "data"? I'm trying to better understand this for myself and can provide code as needed.

```
 data | Fieldtest1 | Fieldtest2 | Fieldtest3 | Fieldtest4 | Fieldtest5 | Fieldtest6
------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

Code:

```
def add_cols(tablename, colnames, data):
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=test_user password=test_password host=localhost port=5432")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    ###Create a new table
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \""+tablename+"\" (data text);")
    ###Layer the new table with column names
    for colname in colnames:
        cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS "+tablename+" ADD IF NOT EXISTS \""+colname+"\" VARCHAR;")
```

Comment: provide the code and more details about the data you are trying to load into your table

Comment: See above. I'm trying to load data from a CSV file directly into PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are specifying it here (in the parentheses):

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \""+tablename+"\" (data text);")
```